# heroku H12 error with Volley

Tags: android, heroku, android-volley

I recently wrote a android app with volley to do the http request,
At first,I used local host to work as a server,it worked perfectly.
However, as I moved my node.js code to heroku server, my app will often get timeout error.
The log from heroku like

```
2016-04-23T00:59:01.653405+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/ispassword" host=lit-island-38801.herokuapp.com request_id=1273b9e7-6632-4117-b68f-5d7d8eb83b52 fwd="152.3.43.156" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=27ms status=200 bytes=224

2016-04-23T00:59:33.426223+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/ispassword" host=lit-island-38801.herokuapp.com request_id=e861aa6f-c40b-440c-af1c-3a24eded9c2c fwd="152.3.43.156" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

And my android app request code is like this

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);

    StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,response);
                    if(response.equals("no")){
                        onLoginFailed();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  //show the toast for a long time
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Login.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String del =":";
                    String []res = response.split(del);
                    fetched_pw = res[1].replaceAll("\\}","").replaceAll("\"","").replaceAll("\\]","");
                    Log.i(TAG,fetched_pw);
                    Log.i(TAG,password);
                    Log.i(TAG,"version1");
                    if(password.equals(fetched_pw)){
                        progressDialog.show();
                        onLoginSuccess();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    else{
                        onLoginFailed();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(strRequest);
}
```

And my node.js code to handle this is like

```
app.post('/ispassword', function (req, res) {
    var pg = require('pg');
    var ans;
    pg.defaults.ssl = true;
    pg.connect("postgres://abcdefghij:ev0Y_GVqmX5zd22oM3KQ8smXS5@ec2-11-11-11-111-1-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d4drnop61h6hv7", function(err, client) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Get to Function ispassword');
            var email = req.param('email');
            client.query("select password from USER_TABLE where email = $1;",[email],function (error,results) {
                    if(results.rowCount>0){
                        var que = client.query("select password from USER_TABLE where email = $1;",[email]);
                        //var que = client.query("select password from USER_TABLE");                                                                                             
                        que.on("row", function (row, result) {
                                //console.log(row);                                                                                                                              
                                result.addRow(row);
                            });
                        que.on("end", function (result) {
                                res.send(result.rows);
                            });
                        console.log("send");
                    }
                    else{
                        res.send('no');
                    }

                });
        });
});
```

Can someone save my day please??

Comment: FYI, overtime I got this error, and my app got blocked, I can do restart dyno to make my server works fine again----though it will only last for couple of minutes